# where has the text search shortcut Ctrl+Shift+L gone in Eclipse Kepler?

Tags: eclipse, search, text, eclipse-kepler

Although, not the ideal way, text search in all documents using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> was a great convenience in Eclipse and neither is it working in Eclipse Kepler nor can I find a key binding to do the same.

The next closest option is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> that searches text that you have already selected or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> and then full search a resource
[image: Eclipse Kepler key binding]

[image: Eclipse Juno key binding]

Comment: AFAIR Ctrl+Shift+L would bring up a list of available key bindings.

Comment: Just verified and attached picture from Juno, it does exist.

Comment: Probably came from some plugin. As you can see it is also a `show key assist` like I told you.

Comment: Looks like it might be the [Quick Search for Eclipse](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/quick-search-eclipse) plugin in the marketplace

Answer (score 1):

Go to market places>>type quick search in search box and click enter. 
It will show you STS with quick search. Install this.
Now you are ready to do ctrl + Shift + L

Answer (score 0):

For Windows Pc Try With This :

**Ctrl+Alt+Shift** then press **L** key.

Answer (score 0):

The keyboard shortcut is now `CTRL`+`Alt`+`Shift`+L.

Ref
[Ctrl + Shift + L Quick Search is not working in STS Spring Tools 4 and Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62472780/ctrl-shift-l-quick-search-is-not-working-in-sts-spring-tools-4-and-eclipse)