# Ctrl + Shift + L Quick Search is not working in STS Spring Tools 4 and Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts, spring-tool-suite, spring-tools-4

I have installed new version of Spring Tools 4.6.2 and Quicksearch (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>) doesn't work, it shows the *"Show Key assist"* instead.

I didn't find any post here related to this.

Is it really bug in newer version or let me know alternate shortcuts for this key assists

Comment: Quick Search became part of the Eclipse platform some time ago. It can be found in _Search > Quick Search_ and the default key is Ctrl+Alt+Shift+L.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Eclipse Luna Quick Search Command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24703393/eclipse-luna-quick-search-command)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The keyboard shortcut is now <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>. Some background as to why...

The STS Quick Search was contributed to Eclipse and is now bundled with Eclipse proper. However, the old keyboard shortcut has a conflict with "Show Key Assist" keyboard shortcut and this was not acceptable. So, when we contributed Quick Search to Eclipse, we had to pick something else for a shortcut.

If you don't care much about the "Show Key Assist" having a shortcut and are already used to <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> for quicksearch. you can change the keybinding via Eclipse preference.